# What's the reason behind the bending of light around the edges of the body in diffraction phenomenon?

Tags: diffraction

I am thinking that gravity influence this phenomenon, what about you guys?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! What are your thoughts? Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows insufficient prior research. Please read this meta post: [What counts as sufficient prior research when asking a question?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5778)

Answer (score 1):

An iteraction of the EM field (photon) with the EM field which extends into the slit.  Even single photons diffract.  As above you can use the Hyugens concept that breaks the wave front up into even intervals. Or you could use Feynman's concept of a line integral, photons like to travel with a path length equal to an integer times its wavelength.   Same result, the Feynman concept is more modern and applies to a broader set of problems.

Answer (score 0):

No, the effect of gravity is orders of magnitude smaller than what you see.

Consider light as a wave. It's like any other wave, like a wave in water.
It has a *wave front* which, for all practical purposes is like a line of little floats, all bobbing up and down in unison.

Each little float sends out circular waves in all directions, but the waves of neighboring floats interfere and cancel each other out, so that the only part of the wave that isn't canceled out is the part going straight ahead.

But, if there's an edge of a wall in the way, so the waves on one side are blocked, then the waves from the floats near the wall are not cancelled out on the side toward the wall, so they can "bend around".

So to understand how waves behave, think in terms of *self-interference*.

Comment: Water waves have a medium to travel on. Light does not. What is the wave made of and what does it travel on? Consider light as a particle.

Comment: @BillAlsept: Light behaves as both particle and wave. See [*double-slit experiment.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment) Also, check out [*Maxwell's equations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations).